# Type Error when trying to create HTML element from the ts file in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I trying to convert `JS` code into `TYPE-SCRIPT` and to create HTML element from the `ts` when i trying to do this:

```
createSvgElem(name: string, attributes: any) {
    let node = document.createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', name);
      for (let name in attributes) {
        node.setAttribute()
      }
  }
```

It giving an Error: `Property 'setAttribute' does not exist on type 'Attr'.`

The original format (worked perfect inside a js file):

```
HocrProofreader.prototype.createSvgElem = function (name, attributes) {
    var node = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', name);
    for (var name in attributes) {
        node.setAttribute(name, attributes[name]);
    }
    return node;
},
```

What is the way to do it right?

[EDIT] 
After changing to `createElementNS` Works fine, but not a cant access the `linkedNode`  property

```
const rectNode = this.createSvgElem('rect', {
          'x': options.bbox[0],
          'y': options.bbox[1],
          'width': options.bbox[2] - options.bbox[0],
          'height': options.bbox[3] - options.bbox[1],
          'id': node.id,
          'bbox': node.title,
          'class': className
        });
        parentRectsNode.appendChild(rectNode);

        // cross-link both nodes:
        rectNode.linkedNode = node;
        node.linkedNode = rectNode;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `setAttribute` is not a property of 'Attr' type .  `setAttribute` exists on type `Element` in typescript.  The `createAttributeNS` function returns an attribute so `Attr` type is assigned implicitly to `node`.

The reason it is not a property on type `Attr` is `setAttribute()` method adds the specified attribute to an **element**, and gives it the specified value, and you cannot do that to an **attribute** in javascript and typescript.

**Update after original issue fixed:**

The `createElementNS`method with namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` returns an `SVGElement` so  the typescript compiler implicitly assigns `SVGElement` type to the `node` variable. As you return this node from the fucntion, `const rectNode = this.createSvgElem` will implicitly assign `SVGElement` type to `rectNode` constant. As `SVGElement` does not have a `linkedNode` property in javascript and typescript, you are getting this error.

If you want to assign custom objects to the `rectNode`, you can try `any` type:

```
const rectNode:any = this.createSvgElem('rect', {
          'x': options.bbox[0],
          'y': options.bbox[1],
          'width': options.bbox[2] - options.bbox[0],
          'height': options.bbox[3] - options.bbox[1],
          'id': node.id,
          'bbox': node.title,
          'class': className
        });
        parentRectsNode.appendChild(rectNode);

        // cross-link both nodes:
        rectNode.linkedNode = node;
        node.linkedNode = rectNode;
      }
```

Comment: Here it worked perfectly `HocrProofreader.prototype.createSvgElem = function (name, attributes) {
    var node = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', name);
    for (var name in attributes) {
        node.setAttribute(name, attributes[name]);
    }
    return node;
},
`

Comment: Yes because `createElementNS` returns and html element but `createAttributeNS` returns and attribute. html elements have setAttrubute method in javascript but attributes dont.

Comment: Now I getting this error `Property 'linkedNode' does not exist on type 'SVGElement'`

Comment: Please share the code where you are trying to access `linkedNode` property